# Problem with Angular 6 Validator for form in table Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I'm building an app with Angular 6 and I have a problem with reactive forms.I'm learning Angular. I have a form for all the rows of a table with one input to validate, which is PRODUCT_QUANTITY. When the number input changes, it submits the form to update the table with the new value. The problem is when I focus on the element and I don't change the value, the validator error is activated for all the rows of the table. I want this activation only for the row concerned when the quantity is not set. Sorry if my code isn't perfect.
Could you help me to solve this problem? Thank you

Here's the code :

**tables.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
<ng-container>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="Filter par type de produit"
                    multiple (selectionChange)="displayData($event.value)"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedProductsId"
                    #productIdSelect="ngModel">
            <button
                    mat-raised-button
                    class="mat-warn fill text-sm"
                    (click)="emptyFilter(productIdSelect,ids)">
                Supprimer filtre
            </button>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let product of productListType" [value]="product.PRODUCTS_id">{{product.PRODUCTS_title}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="addProductToList()">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>


            <ng-container matColumnDef="PRODUCT_name">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Nom du produit</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.PRODUCT_name}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="PRODUIT_TYPE">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Type de produit</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.PRODUIT_TYPE}}</td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="PRODUCT_QUANTITY">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Quantité</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                    <mat-form-field style="width: 50%">
                        <input (change)="setIdProduct(row.PRODUCT_id)" formControlName="quantity" matInput min="0" type="number" placeholder="Quantité" value="{{row.PRODUCT_QUANTITY}}">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="PRODUCT_COMMENT">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Commentaire</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                    <mat-form-field style="width: 60%">
                        <textarea (change)="setIdProduct(row.PRODUCT_id)" formControlName="remark" matInput placeholder="Ajouter un commentaire"
                                  value="{{row.PRODUCT_COMMENT}}"></textarea>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="VALIDATE">
                <th style="display: none" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Ajouter un produit</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                    <button id="submitForProduct" style="display: none;" mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Ajouter à ma liste de
                        course
                    </button>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>

    </form>

    <mat-paginator [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**tables.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator, MatSnackBar, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import {ProductService} from '../../services/product.service';
import {Product} from '../../models/product';
import {ProductType} from '../../models/producttype';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, NgModel, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {forEach} from 'async';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-tables',
    templateUrl: './tables.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tables.component.scss']
})
export class TablesComponent implements OnInit {
    displayedColumns = ['PRODUCT_name', 'PRODUIT_TYPE', 'PRODUCT_QUANTITY', 'PRODUCT_COMMENT', 'VALIDATE'];
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Product>;
    productListType: ProductType[];
    productListItem: Product[] = [];
    filteredArray: Product[] = [];
    selectedProductsId: ProductType[];
    ids: any[] = [];
    form: FormGroup;
    response: Subscription;
    idProduct: number;


    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

    constructor(private productProvider: ProductService, private addProduct: FormBuilder, private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
        console.log(this.productListItem);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.productProvider.getAllProducts().subscribe(
            r => {
                this.productListType = r['products'] as ProductType[];
                this.productListType.forEach(product => {
                    this.ids.push(product.PRODUCTS_id);
                    product.PRODUCTS_products.forEach(productItem => {
                        this.productListItem.push(new Product(
                            productItem.PRODUCT_id,
                            productItem.PRODUCT_name,
                            productItem.PRODUCT_unit,
                            product.PRODUCTS_title,
                            product.PRODUCTS_id,
                            0,
                            ''));
                    });
                });
                this.productProvider.getProductsHousehold(1).subscribe(
                    result => {
                        this.productListItem.map(productItem => {
                            result.products.map(productItemR => {
                                if (productItemR.PRODUCTS_LIST_id_prod === productItem.PRODUCT_id) {
                                    console.log(productItemR.PRODUCTS_LIST_QUANTITY);
                                    productItem.PRODUCT_QUANTITY = productItemR.PRODUCTS_LIST_quantity;
                                    productItem.PRODUCT_COMMENT = productItemR.PRODUCTS_LIST_remark;
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        console.log(this.productListItem)
                    });
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Product>(this.productListItem);
                this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
                this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            });
        this.form = this.addProduct.group({
            quantity: ['', [Validators.required]],
            remark: ['']
        });
    }

// filter the list of products
    applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
        filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
        if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
            this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
        }
    }

//Display data when filter changed    
    displayData(event) {
        let array: any;
        array = event;
        if (array.length === 0) {
            array = this.ids;
        }
        console.log(array);
        this.filteredArray = [];
        this.productListType.forEach(product => {
            array.forEach(productId => {
                if (product.PRODUCTS_id === productId) {
                    product.PRODUCTS_products.forEach(pro => {
                        this.filteredArray.push(new Product(
                            pro.PRODUCT_id,
                            pro.PRODUCT_name,
                            pro.PRODUCT_unit,
                            product.PRODUCTS_title,
                            product.PRODUCTS_id,
                            pro.PRODUCT_QUANTITY,
                            pro.PRODUCT_COMMENT));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Product>(this.filteredArray);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    }
//empty the filter
    emptyFilter(select
                    :
                    NgModel, values
    ) {
        select.update.emit([]);
        this.displayData([]);
    }

//set Id Product and trigger event submit
    setIdProduct(PRODUCT_id
                     :
                     number
    ) {
        this.idProduct = PRODUCT_id;
        console.log(this.idProduct);
        document.getElementById('submitForProduct').click();
    }

// function called when the form is submitted    
    addProductToList() {
        if (this.form.invalid || this.idProduct < 0) {
            this.snackBar.open('Veuillez renseigner tous les champs', '', {
                duration: 2000
            });
            return;
        }
        const quantity = this.form.controls.quantity.value;
        const remark = this.form.controls.remark.value;
        this.response = this.productProvider.addProductToList(this.idProduct, 1, quantity, remark).subscribe(
            result => {
                if (result === true) {
                    this.snackBar.open('Le produit a bien été ajouté à la liste', '', {
                        duration: 2000
                    });
                } else {
                    this.snackBar.open('Produit non ajouté à la liste', '', {
                        duration: 2000
                    });
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: a minimal stackblitz would make it easier for anyone to help you here

Comment: You are using the same formControl for all rows of the column. So if the validation fires in any one row it will be reflected throughout the column. Use formArray or an array of formControls to solve the problem.

Comment: @AIqbalRaj it's a great idea but my database is external. That's why I didn't do that.

Comment: @Gokul thank you for your answer, what's the best solution and how I do that?

Comment: I have an example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-ReactiveForms/tree/master/Demo-Final

Comment: @DeborahK Thank you, I will try it. If I adapt it for my material table, it will work? Because I don't have ngFor in my code.

Comment: My example doesn't do a material table. But a prior comment suggested a formArray and my code demonstrates how to use a formArray. Maybe someone else has an example specifically for material tables.

Comment: Anyone to help me?